# Need help on where-object in powershell

Tags: powershell

if I execute the below code it is not filtering, it is returning all the results.

[image]

$R datatype is below
[image]

Comment: As tip for future questions: **don't** add images of code in the question. Instead add the code as [Formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` creates a `[scriptblock]` literal, the value of which will always evaluate to `$True` when cast to `[bool]`.

Remove the `{}` around the comparisons inside the filter block:

```
$filteredRows = $R |Where-Object {$_.db_sync_state -eq 'NOT SYNCHRONIZING' -or -not $_.is_failover_ready}
```

As [Gert Jan Kraaijeveld mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855592/need-help-on-where-object-in-powershell/64855771?noredirect=1#comment114666541_64855771), you can use `()` to group the individual comparisons if required:

```
$filteredRows = $R |Where-Object {($_.db_sync_state -eq 'NOT SYNCHRONIZING') -or (-not $_.is_failover_ready)}
```

Comment: If you like to structure the filter (I personally do) you can use parentheses: `$filteredRows = $R |Where-Object {($_.db_sync_state -eq 'NOT SYNCHRONIZING') -or (-not $_.is_failover_ready)}`

Comment: @Hussain That's great! Please consider marking the answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left